# update depth exceeded using redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form, redux-form-validators

I am trying to get validate redux-form dependent on drop-down value selection, below are the code and error.

I am getting `Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.` This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate`. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Please help me and Thanks in advance

```
    ...
      <Field
        id="user-form-email"
        name="email"
        component={emailField}
        className={style.inputField}
        fullWidth
        label={i18n({ id: "users.email" })}
        validate={[emailRequiredForAdmin("role")]}
        disabled={selectedRole === "manager"}
      />

      <Field
        id="user-form-roles"
        name="role"
        component={userRoleSelectField}
        className={style.inputField}
        fullWidth={true}
        items={getRoles(intl)}
        label={i18n({ id: "users.role" })}
        onChange={(event) => {
          if (event.target.value == "user") {
            this.props.change("password", "");
            this.props.change("confirmPassword", "");
          }
        }}
      />
    ...

// Decorate with redux-form

UsersForm = reduxForm({
  form: formNames.USER,
})(UsersForm);

const selector = formValueSelector(formNames.USER);

UsersForm = connect((state) => {
  const selectedRole = selector(state, "role");
  return {
    selectedRole,
  };
});
```

Errors:

```
    The above error occurred in the <Form(Connect(UsersForm))> component:
    in Form(Connect(UsersForm)) (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Connect(Form(Connect(UsersForm))))
    in Connect(Form(Connect(UsersForm))) (created by ReduxForm)
    in ReduxForm (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Hoc (created by ReduxForm)
    in ReduxForm (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Users)
    in Users (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by _temp)
    in _temp (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (created by App)
    in Switch (created by App)
    in div (created by RoutesContainer)
    in RoutesContainer (created by App)
    in div (created by Container)
    in Container (created by App)
    in div (created by Layout)
    in Layout (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (created by RootApp)
    in Switch (created by RootApp)
    in MuiPickersUtilsProvider (created by RootApp)
    in ThemeProvider (created by RootApp)
    in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
    in ConnectedRouter (created by Context.Consumer)
    in ConnectedRouterWithContext (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by RootApp)
    in Provider (created by RootApp)
    in RootApp (created by LocalizedApp)
    in IntlProvider (created by LocalizedApp)
    in LocalizedApp

    Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
        at checkForNestedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:23093)
        at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21164)
        at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:15660)
        at Subscription.checkForUpdates (connectAdvanced.js:101)
        at Subscription.handleChangeWrapper (Subscription.js:100)
        at eval (Subscription.js:26)
        at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21856)
        at Object.notify (Subscription.js:22)
        at Subscription.notifyNestedSubs (Subscription.js:95)
        at Subscription.checkForUpdates (connectAdvanced.js:90)
```

Comment: Are you changing the state inside `userRoleSelectField`, `emailField`, or any other field component?

Answer (score 2):

You should not call a function inside validate array. Do it like this instead.

```js
    // Outside of the component, if possible: 
    const emailRequiredForAdminValidator = emailRequiredForAdmin("role")

    // Or useMemo if you need component state, and you have to put any
    // value used in the `emailRequiredForAdmin` in that `useMemo` deps array
    const emailRequiredForAdminValidator = useMemo(() => 
      emailRequiredForAdmin("role")
    , [/* deps here */]);
    
    <Field
        id="user-form-email"
        name="email"
        component={emailField}
        className={style.inputField}
        fullWidth
        label={i18n({ id: "users.email" })}
        validate={[emailRequiredForAdminValidator]}
        disabled={selectedRole === "manager"}
      />
```

This is because every time the component is re-rendered the function userRoleSelectField is called again, and that causes the component to re-render again, thus causing an infinite loop.

Basically, as pointed out by @diedu, any function called at render, (such as `userRoleSelectField`, `emailField` or `emailRequiredForAdminValidator`...) and that cause another render, for example by calling `setState`, will result in a call stack overflow.

Comment: What if that function returns another function that contains the actual logic? My point is that the definition of that function isn't shown and the assumption that it changes state is still an assumption..

Comment: it doesn't matter if the definition of the function changes the state or not, the function returned will always be created again whenever the component re-renders. Due to this the Field component will be re-registered causing the entire form to re-render. Then again a new function will be created and thus an infinite loop will occur. Check the validate prop in redux form documentation at this link: https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/field.md/

Comment: That doesn't make sense at all. According to that link `Note: if the validate prop changes the field will be re-registered` well the prop isn't changing, it's being set for the first time so that doesn't apply unless that function changes state. The result of the call is what is passed in. Also according to that link `All other props will be passed along to the element generated by the component prop` implying that passed in component will be calling validate. Moreover if this is the answer I'd expect that the OP would have selected it and awarded the rep by now unless theyre tryna stiff you.

Comment: If that truly was the case I'd expect `label` to also incur the same issue.

Comment: Checkout out official react documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html.
It says that a new arrow functions will be created whenever the component will re render. Normally the props will not change and component wont re-render . But here on every re-render a new function will be created, so old props won't be same as new prop.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Nitin Garg. You should not call a function while assigning to a component property. If you need to call you can use arrow function.

```
validate={[emailRequiredForAdmin("role")]}
```

becomes

```
validate={[() => { emailRequiredForAdmin("role"); } ]}
```